# problems deploying my create-react-app application on a cloud hosting

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, dev-to-production, build-dependencies

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku. I chose Heroku and I'm using the free stuff, I don't know if it has something to do with it, I could have chosen another one. For example, I tried to deploy it on DigitalOcean, and it never ended, so I canceled it after 1 1/2 hours

It seems to be a memory limit problem

If I execute "npm run start" or "npm run build" on my machine, everything works perfectly

**EDIT**

After searching the internet I found a way to fix the memory limit.

It was adding a new variable to Heroku: NODE_OPTIONS variable, value: --max_old_space_size=1024

But the problem wasn't fixed

Now, the build log is this:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.13.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.5.4
       
       Resolving node version 16.13.0...
       Downloading and installing node 16.13.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 8.5.4 (replacing 8.1.0)...
       npm 8.5.4 installed
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: serenity-sc@0.1.0
       npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
       npm ERR! node_modules/react
       npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
       npm ERR!   react-dom@"^16.13.0" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.GYeHW/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.GYeHW/_logs/2022-03-24T16_42_31_990Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

As you can see, the problem has to do with the react version or something like that

Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

The git hub is https://github.com/rafaelsoteldosilva/serenity-sc

In the project, I use: create-react-app, react-three-fiber, styled-components

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: Did you try to run npm install -g serve, serve -s build to check if the build run on your local development?

Comment: with npm run build you generate the build, but then you need to run serve -s build to start the local server and verify if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: I found out that it wasn't a problem with the app itself, but with the dependencies versions, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Describe your problem, I can try to help you